# ¿cómo puedo aplicar "hover" a los elementos "a" en CSS?

Tags: css, html5, html-select, hover, selectores-css

Estoy tratando de aplicar la pseudoclase "hover" al elemento "a" para que cuando el cursor pase sobre un link este cambie su color, pero CSS no me lee el selector
**.header .top-header .contenedor .top-menu ul li a:hover{}**

¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona este selector?

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="top-header">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="top-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACERCA DE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="top-redes">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tu código funciona lo acabo de probar, ¿a qué elemento a se lo tratas de aplicar?

Comment: Pues con solo hacer: `a:hover{ algo }` funcionará para todos tus enlaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si desea aplicar el estilo solo a `class="top-menu"`, entonces es suficiente

```
.top-menu a:hover{color:red}
```

Si, por el contrario, desea aplicar el estilo a `class="top-menu"` y `class="top-redes"`, dado el tu DOM, entonces es suficiente

```
.header a:hover{color:red}
```

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Answer (score 3):

Al probar lo que tienes ahí solo funciona para la primer lista porque estás acotando que el hover se aplique solo al contenedor con la clase  top-menu. Si dejas lo siguiente .header .top-header .contenedor ul li a:hover{} se aplicará para todos los  que estén dentro de .contenedor ul li.

```css
.header .top-header .contenedor ul li a:hover{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="top-header">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="top-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACERCA DE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="top-redes">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```